# Argument of type 'Observable<Response>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, webpack-2

i have no idea...

angular 2, webpack 2

```
public doSomething(myParam: Observable<Response>) { ... }

...

myMethod() {
    doSomething(this.http.get(...))
}
```

Comment: Please include a more detailed description of your issue including more details of your code (how and what stuff is imported ect.) and write in full sentences - It is also not very polite to bluntly downvote someone who has taken the time to try helping you with your issue even though your question is formed very poorly.

Answer (score 8):

import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";

will solve the issue.

One Response Object comes from "@angular/http" and the other comes from "es6lib.d.ts" or something like that

Answer (score 1):

use this code in order to remove error

```
public doSomething(myParam: any) { ... }

...

myMethod() {
    doSomething(this.http.get(...))
}
```

PS:- use this method just to remove error of yours, this is not preferable method, also please post more and explanation why your code throwing error.

Comment: @PardeerJain, hide the error does not solve the error

Comment: @user2606780 Downvotes should be used for "invalid" answers - while this might not be the most perfect answer, it is at least an answer, given the fact that you provided close to zero information regarding your issue.

Comment: well said @olsn , also i mentioned in my answer , questioner have to provide more information to make question more clear

Comment: In my case: I use get() method of angular/http service. This service returns Observable<Response> from rxjs. Iam import rxjs to my component and want to use type hinting in my method but take error(look at the subject of question).

Comment: roughly speaking, why Observable<Response> not a Observable<Response>?